# Running peer block lowers the CPU usage - Am I being hacked?

Tags: ip, malware, cpu-usage, internet-security

Why is it when I start peer block my CPU usage goes down 20%?

I've been using peer block not because IO'm file sharing but because I just want to better secure my computer.

I use its default p2p and spyware lists as well as some bluetrack spyware, threats and hijacked lists.

What I usually see is being blocked is "private-use networks", "link local block", and "bogon".

Occasionally it blocks Microsoft or apple IPs which is wtv.

I keep my computer up to date (allowed the software update IPs) and I run a virus scan every day. What it shows in the task manager is three types of SVhost is using that cpu usage.

Why is this happening? Should I be concerned that maybe peer block is blocking some malicious stuff? I think i will stick with peerblock as it frees up a good amount of CPU usage.

Should I and other normal casual users use peer block to protect their computers?

Comment: It might help to see *where* this cpu usage was. 20% is a *non trivial* amount of processor.

Comment: I look in task manager but all i see is three different types of schost. How can i get a more detailed view?

Comment: Resource manager, assuming you're using a modern version of windows

Comment: Ok so the first few things that popped up when i disabled peer block were BFE, SystemEventBroker and MPsSvc under services. And schost.exe (localserviceNoNetwork), (LocalServiceNetworkRestricted), and (dcomLaunch) in processes. Ill try to replicate these to verify these always come up. I dont know what any of these mean. I look it up and they seem to be like normal window proccesses. Btw i have windows 10